# Mac File System - Knows Where Moved Files Are?

Tags: mac, hfs

Maybe it's just me, but it seems like Mac OS knows where a file is even when it's moved.  Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: Of course it does. You use Mac OS to move the file, after all. :)

Comment: There are several ways to interpret this question. [My answer to a question on Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7707/how-do-open-files-behave-on-linux-systems/7712#7712) is responsive to one of them, as it discusses the internals of traditional unix filesystems (which---[tobylane notes below](http://superuser.com/questions/268371/mac-file-system-knows-where-moved-files-are/268401#268401)---HFS+ shares).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the file's path, Mac OS aliases record several pieces of additional information: the file's unique ID, its parent directory ID, file size, [possibly creation time]; which are used to locate the most probable match in case of a broken link. I think most of the time a file is found by its unique ID, which does not change after a rename.

See also [*Alias (Mac OS)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28Mac_OS%29) on Wikipedia.

Comment: By the way, Windows is able to fix broken shortcuts in a very similar way (using an unique ID first, the file's timestamps and size if the ID lookup fails).

Answer (score 5):

The Mac file system is called [HFS+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS+). It uses [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) numbers in a [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), with the physical and logical location (three parts in total). Metadata is in another b-tree, along with the data-forks.

So it knows what to expect in a place, knows of another way to refer to it, looks that up and there you go. It's like if someone moved house, you still have their mobile phone number to call.